# Can I use an Uno Cross-Platform Library within a UWP app?

Tags: uno-platform

I've created an Uno cross-platform library that includes a few different Uno controls.

Is it possible to use this library within a UWP project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've used cross-platform APIs (eg from `Windows.UI.Xaml.*` namespaces) and haven't used platform-specific APIs, then yes you can reference this library from a UWP project, as you would any other library.